# Nativescript-vue webview auto play video

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I think what I’ve learned from this answer is that autoplaying videos in a webview inline (a term I think means “not full view”?) on iOS isn’t possible unless you add code to tns-core-modules?
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5726#issuecomment-383860590
am I right?

Comment: Yes, correct. Do you have any issue exactly

Comment: @Manoj just have a requirement to autoplay a video inside a webview in a nativescript-vue app. Android works fine, but iOS doesn't play the video.

Comment: It's not playing in fullscreen or it doesn't play at all. Please share a Playground sample.

Comment: It doesn't play at all. The requirements also say to remove the controls (it's just a short 2 sec mp4 for a tutorial) so the user just sees the first frame of the video. Requirements state the video should play inline (not full screen).

Comment: As mentioned above please share Playground where issue can be reproduced.

Comment: have you found a solution for this ? what eventually you did ?